# Rust Borrrow Checker - passing a mutable variable as mutable to a fn and get ownership back

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am fiddling with writing a Lexer that takes an input `&str` and returns an `Iterator` over the tokens I generate for the input:

```rust
pub enum Token<'a> {
    Lparen(&'a str),         // (
    Rparen(&'a str),         // )
    Lbrack(&'a str),         // [

    // -- snip --
}

pub fn tokenize(input: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = Token> {
    let mut chars = input.char_indices();

    std::iter::from_fn(move || {

        if let Some(next) = chars.next() {

            let (start, c) = next;
            let end = start + 1;

            return match c {
                '(' => Some(Token::Lparen(&input[start..end])),
                ')' => Some(Token::Rparen(&input[start..end])),
                '[' => Some(Token::Lbrack(&input[start..end])),

                '='  => from_eq(input, start, chars),
                // move of chars occurs here  ^^^^^

                // -- snip --

                _ => Some(Token::Unknown(&input[start..end])),
            }

        }

        None
    })
}

fn from_eq<'a>(input: &'a str, start: usize, mut chars: CharIndices) -> Option<Token<'a>> {
    // -- snip --
}
```

I am moving `chars` into the closure and within the closure I pass it on to `from_eq`. `from_eq` is supposed to iterate further on `chars` with a specific handling of the characters it finds.

Now of course, I the borrow checker nags at me

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `chars`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
   --> src/lib.rs:106:47
    |
94  |       let mut chars = input.char_indices();
    |           --------- captured outer variable
95  | 
96  |       std::iter::from_fn(move || {
    |  ________________________-
97  | |
98  | |         if let Some(next) = chars.next() {
99  | |
...   |
106 | |                 '='  => from_eq(input, start, chars),
    | |                                               ^^^^^ move occurs because `chars` has type `CharIndices<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...   |
122 | |         None
123 | |     })
    | |_____- captured by this `FnMut` closure
```

My vague understanding is that I pass a mutable reference to `from_eq` which is also mutable outside of its scope, so now I would have two owners which is not ok.

I don't know how if my understanding is correct though or how to handle it even. I want to mutate `chars` in both functions, I am sure once `from_eq` has run, it's not mutating `chars` anymore—but how do I comply with the borrow checker here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `from_eq()` returned `Some(...)`. Next iteration of the returned iterator, `std::iter::from_fn()` will call the closure again and it in its turn will call `chars.next()`. But `chars` was moved into `from_eq()` in the previous iteration!

This is what the compiler says: [`from_fn()` takes a `FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html), and you cannot move a captured variable - `chars` - in a `FnMut` closure, because it can be called again and the variable will now be in invalid state.

The solution is to borrow `chars` in `from_eq()` instead of moving it:

```rust
fn from_eq<'a>(input: &'a str, start: usize, chars: &mut CharIndices) -> Option<Token<'a>> { ... }
```

```rust
'=' => from_eq(input, start, &mut chars),
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually passing a mutable reference to `from_eq`. That's precisely the problem. You're *moving* `chars` into `from_eq` as a mutable argument. Once you've moved a value in Rust, you can't use it anymore, this is why you're getting the error.

But to use an iterator you only need a mutable reference to it, let's change `from_eq`'s signature to reflect that:

```
fn from_eq<'a>(input: &'a str, start: usize, chars: &mut CharIndices) -> Option<Token<'a>> {
    // -- snip --
}
```

And in the calling code, we can use the `by_ref()` method provided by `Iterator` to pass `chars` in:

```
return match c {
    '(' => Some(Token::Lparen(&input[start..end])),
    ')' => Some(Token::Rparen(&input[start..end])),
    '[' => Some(Token::Lbrack(&input[start..end])),

    '='  => from_eq(input, start, chars.by_ref()),
    // --------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
    // pass in `chars` by mutable reference instead of by value

    // -- snip --

    _ => Some(Token::Unknown(&input[start..end])),
}
```

Comment: Ah, mutable REF instead of mutable value! Thank you!